# I am trying to run a batch command from PowerShell

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I have run into a character limitation for `net.exe`

```
net localgroup administrators "domainname\G-%COMPUTERNAME%-LocalAdmins" /add
```

I have been told you can run this through PowerShell, but I have been unsuccessful.  Here is what I have come up with:

```
powershell -command "& {([adsi]'LDAP://./localgroup,administrators').Add('LDAP://domainname/G-%COMPUTERNAME%-LocalAdmins,Administrators');}"
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a day or so of research I found a microsoft forum by Jaap Brasser.  He has written a script that I could invoke with my parameters and get to work...

powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -file "\server\pub\DomainAdmin\SetADAccounts.ps1" -Computer %COMPUTERNAME% -Trustee domainname\G-%COMPUTERNAME%-LocalAdmins

Thank you for your input..

Comment: https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Add-AD-UserGroup-to-Local-fe5e9239

Answer (score 1):

You can run external commands (like `net.exe`) from PowerShell practically the same way you can run them from CMD. However, if you want to use (environment) variables you have to use PowerShell variable syntax (`$var` or `$env:var` respectively). PowerShell doesn't recognize CMD/batch variable syntax (`%var%`).

This should work:

```
net localgroup administrators "domainname\G-${env:COMPUTERNAME}-LocalAdmins" /add
```

Comment: OK thanks... I will try that an post how far I get... Wait, the net command I had will work with a shorter variable, just not with mine (which is over the 20 Character limitation).  I have been told that you should be able to perform this action via a powershell cmd to get over the 20 Character limitation of the net cmd.  However, I will look into the $env:var and see if I can invoke a script to perform this action instead of a simple cmd.

Answer (score 0):

Per Microsoft:

> The NET.EXE command does not support names longer than 20 characters for reasons of backward compatibility with LAN Manager 2.0.

Yes, Windows commands will pass variables to PowerShell. If the member is on the same domain, it does not need to be included. Use the Add-LocalGroupMember cmdlet.

```
PowerShell Add-LocalGroupMember -Group Administrators -Member 'G-%COMPUTERNAME%-LocalAdmins'
```